# How to make a call to controller multiple times to get chunks of data from the whole - Java, Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to display the content of very huge log file (2GB - 5GB) on the browser window.

If I send the log file to JSP from controller and set the content to window.open from JSP, then it is a very big pain to load the page.

Or If I set the entire content of the log file to a StringBuilder in server Side(Controller) and send it back to JSP, then the page needs to be on wait for a whole time till all the log is set to StringBuilder.

So I want to send a chunks of data to the JSP in each call.

Example:
In the first call from JSP to Controller, i will send back first 20 lines
In the second call from JSP to Controller, i will send back next 20 lines

Or is there any other best way i can do this?

Please help me out in this...

Comment: Any specific reason you are considering ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do it setup a controller to take a size and start location

page 1 would be
    http://www.site.com/_internal/logtail?characters=100000&start=0

page 2 would be
    http://www.site.com/_internal/logtail?characters=100000&start=100000

You can then use the Random Access File in java to seek to the Nth location and read N characters.  if someone wants another page, you increase the start location and keep going via ajax

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

(Side Note: I often use _internal to denote a protected url. This is something I setup on sites with the use of ACL's [Access control list] to protect that url so only a limited set of people can access it - I assume you probably don't want the public seeing your log files.  If its a protected site anyway you may not need to worry)